# Istio Circuit Breaker Fallback

Tags: spring-boot, istio, hystrix, circuit-breaker

I'm exploring Istio's circuit breaker and wan't to setup fallback methods if the circuit trips.

I have a few Spring boot applications that are deployed on kubernetes and with Istio's circuit breaking defined in DestinationRule.

I can see that my caller application gets a 503 Service Unavailable exception when I intentionally bring down the called service.

I'm looking for design patterns or libraries with which I can define fallback methods for my rest calls,
something similar to @HystrixCommand.

I checked out [spring-cloud-circuitBreaker](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-circuitbreaker#overview) but that doesn't support Istio.
I have also explored ClientHttpRequestInterceptor with Spring RestTemplate, and can catch all ServiceUnavailable exceptions, but I need a way to configure different fallback methods to different REST calls.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "istio support", as the Istio circuit breaker and spring's one is in fact a difference thing